# modifying keys in sessions with connect-mongo express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test'
  }),
  secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
  cookie: {maxAge: 3600000*24*7}
}));
```

i have this for sessions, and it generates ObjectID.
how can i modify ObjectID?

- if this is a duplicate please direct me the link Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can access by this method:

```
req.sessionID
```